# tar - Remove leading directory components on extraction

Tags: linux, tar

How can you extract only the target dir and not the complete dir tree?

#### compress

```
tar cf /var/www_bak/site.tar /var/www/site
```

#### extract

```
tar xf /var/www/site.tar -C /tmp
```

This will produce:

```
/tmp/var/www/site
```

How is it possible to avoid the whole dir tree to be created when the file is extracted?

What I want it to extract to:

```
/tmp/site
```

Answer (score 440, accepted):

You want to use the `--strip-components=NUMBER` option of `tar`:

```
 --strip-components=NUMBER
       strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction
```

Your command would be:

```
tar xfz /var/www/site.gz --strip-components=2 -C /tmp
```

Comment: This answer is better because you do not have to think about it before the tar creation. You can use it with an already created tar file. Thanks @MikeyB !

Comment: I'm pleased to report this works both in GNU tar and BSD tar.

Comment: and because you may not be the tar creator... (or if you're doing it with another tool and that tool does silly things...)

Comment: you might still be missing `--strip-components` flag if you're using busybox-embedded implementation of `tar`, though.

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux Well, yes---if you made a mistake and created an archive that includes leading directories that you do not want to see during extraction. But it's clearer to build the archive without the leading undesirable directories in the first place.

Comment: This is the right answer!

Comment: @NathanOsman this *may* work with some recent versions of GNU tar or its other flavors, but that option is not available in legacy GNU versions that are still out there.

Comment: If you want to remove *all* leading paths then use `--transform='s/^.*\///'` instead of strip-components.

Comment: At least with the FreeBSD 12.3 version of `tar`, `--strip-components=2` would only strip the leading slash and the first dir. To remove all of it, you'll need `--strip-components=3`.

Comment: This also works very well when you change the directory structure in a project, or need to often download design files into a develop repository (e.g. with git archive).

Answer (score 54):

Why not use `-C` option when creating:

```
$ tar cf /var/www/site.tar -C /var/www_bak/ site
```

Comment: TMTOWTDI. That would work too, using the same `-C` option ;)

Comment: He wants to strip the path from some leading components, not change the output directory. See below for the correct answer.

Comment: We can't use it when someone else prepares the archive.

Comment: Because 
```
_t=prefix-$( date +%Y%m%d );
tar -cjf ".backups/$_t.tar.bz2" --transform="s#^(\./)?#$_t/#x;" -- files...;
tar -df ".backups/$_t.tar.bz2" --strip-components=1
```

Comment: This post answers the **wrong** question.